# Java script to jquery mobile: change value on submit click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hello Stackoverflow people!

I'm making a mobile website using the latest jquery mobile (1.2.0). I have a form and I want the submit button change text/value on click. I have a code that works in a empty html page:

```
<body>
    <form method="get" action="/show.php?" target="showframe">
        <select name="week">
            <option value="1">Week</option>
        </select>
        <select name="id">
            <option value="1">ID</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Load" id="show" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('show').value='Refresh'"> 
    </form>
    <iframe id="showframe" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms"></iframe>
<body>
```

But when I copy and past the submut button in my jquery page it wont change value..
My question is: how do i get this to work in jquery mobile? what is an alternative?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have tried jivings answer and this is it:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Infoweb Mobiel - Dominicus College</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/style.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $(this).val('Refresh');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get" action="/show.php?" target="showframe">
        <select name="week">
            <option value="1">Week</option>
        </select>
        <select name="id">
            <option value="1">ID</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Load" id="show" $("#show").button("refresh");> 
    </form>
    <iframe id="showframe" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms"></iframe>
<body>
```

but it doesnt work.. i think im doing something wrong. where and how do i have to place `$("#show").button("refresh");` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the text that you're seeing isn't actually part of the button element. JQuery Mobile pads the button out with it's own elements to create the style you see. If you want it to refresh these elements when you make a change then you need to call the `refresh()` method on the button:

```
$("#show").button("refresh");
```

Also, since this is jQuery, you should be using handlers properly. You onclick should be with the rest of the JavaScript logic, either in the `head` or in an external file and look like this:

```
$("#show").click(function() {
   $(this).val('Refresh');
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response, Sorry I am just a beginner in html/javascript/jquery but can you give me more details please? where do i have to put $("#show").button("refresh"); i added $("#show").click(function() {
   $(this).val('Refresh');
}); to the head.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand few things about the jQuery Mobile:

- What you did in your EDIT part was wrong, you cant use $("#show").button("refresh") in a HTML block. Java script can not be mixed with a HTML like that.
- This is an example how this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8nMX/.

Code:

```
    $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
        $(document).on('click', '#show', function(){
            $('#show').attr('value','Show');
            $('#show').button("refresh");
            $('#custom-form').submit();
        });    
    });
```

In the case of my example ***index*** is an id of my jQuery Mobile page. ***Pagebeforeshow*** is an event that will be triggered before the page can be shown:

```
    $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
```

Your button type was changed to button. Reason is, you cant change button text (or anything else) while form is submitting it data to php server:

```
    <input type="button" value="Load" id="show">
```

That is why we are binding a click event to the button in this line :

```
    $(document).on('click', '#show', function(){
```

Next line, we are changing the button text:

```
    <input type="button" value="Load" id="show">
```

Because this is a jQuery Mobile styled button we need to refresh him so the new style can be applied:

```
    $('#show').button("refresh");
```

Finally we are triggering form submit:

```
    $('#show').button("refresh");
```

Before you continue please read this article: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html. There you will find everything you need to know about jQuery Mobile page events.

Also read this article about anatomy of jQuery Mobile page: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

As you are new to this page take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) article, it will help you get a better response in the future. I hope this was an answer to your question. Feel free to leave a comment if you have more questions.